# Why can't I input text into this <input> field with javascript code? The text flashes back to original value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, applescript

Watch the video to see what I mean exactly https://youtu.be/kvdVNwTjw5c Thank you!

I'm trying to automate login this website [shopee.sg/buyer/login](https://shopee.sg/buyer/login) I need to **input the login name** first but I couldn't do it with my codes, it always changed back to original value after the code is executed. I have used codes `document.getElementsByClassName("_56AraZ")[0].value = "my username";`
or
`document.getElementsByClassName('_56AraZ')[0].setAttribute('value',"my username");` the text in the field appeared on screen to be changed but then the text flashed back to the previous value after I clicked to other field or clicked somewhere else, it didn't really change!
I know this code can be successfully on other websites but this website is tricky for me. Can anyone help me to input text to this field successfuly? Thank you!

Comment: As you already know, you can try using AppleScript to do this, that way your automation tries to simulate what a person would do, instead of doing it via javascript. In my test, what you need to do is send a tab key code, followed by a keystroke of the username. I can give you pseudo code if you'd like, though i use libraries to deal with AS verbosity.

Comment: Thank! I understand that applescript alone can automate it But i still want Javascript to do it for some optimisation reasons. Would you tell me, Is it possible for javascript to do it or it’s impossible with javascript? Why?

Comment: Because I want my script to run in background while doing other things. With AS alone, I have to stop doing things I’m doing for bringing the browser to front, waiting the process to be done. If it can be done with JS, it’s so cool, maybe it isn’t possible? idk.

Comment: I did try to automate some websites using javascript, and tbh some websites are harder to drive than others so it really depends how far you are willing to go to fool the web framework that was used to create the web page. I wouldn't say impossible, but perhaps not easy. You could also try looking at how to send keyboard events using JavaScript.

Comment: Thank for this answer, it's really helpful. I will look it up how to send keyboard events using JavaScript. One more question, Is it hard because the web's developer intentionally made it hard for preventing people creating automate tool or it's just the way how some web frameworks work? I mean did the people creating that web intentionally do it for protection?

Comment: @user3579815  would you give me a simple example of JS keyboard event simulation for my situation, it can just be pressing an "a" key. This stuff is kinda hard for me to understand and find out atm.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something else also tries to write in that field - it may be other script or the browser (saved form data). I suggest you delayed your script with a setTimeout function for some absurd time (like 2 seconds or more) and if it helps, lower the delay to a working, but acceptable value. so your script is the last thing that writes to that field. And/or you can try running it on window.load event.

Comment: I have used it but it didn't work
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementsByClassName("_56AraZ")[0].value = "my username"; }, 3000);
Can you write me some codes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I run this from the console, it works:
`document.getElementsByClassName("_56AraZ")[0].value = "my username";`

So probably you run your code before the input is even created. Let's check it.
Inside the setTimeout callback, insert this:

```
const field = document.querySelector("._56AraZ");
if (field) {
    field.value = "my username";
} else {
    alert('No input field!');
}
```

This should let you know if you try to fill the field too early. If this is the case, you'll have to know somehow when the input field is being created and run your code after it happens. How to do it exactly - I can't tell you as I know nothing about your site's architecture.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Please watch my video, https://youtu.be/kvdVNwTjw5c  . The problem is after entering the code to the console, it worked but then after I click to somewhere on the website, the text I input disappear. I did the second code u gave me but the same problem occured

Comment: OK, I've seen your video and performed similar test. I think you should check the functions attached to onFocus and onBlur of your input field. They probably contain something that clears the input.
Also, look at the onChange listener, it probably prevents from clearing on focus or blur. The onChange event doesn't occur when you fill the field programatcally.

Comment: Thank you mpdoctor! For helping me but i'm newbie and not understanding all the technical terms but I'm trying to learn. I need to learn much more to understand what you said. So atm, can you check what you've said for me? idk how to check it. It's this website https://shopee.sg/buyer/login